# Shell Script to connect to Database and execute query

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!bin/bash
Query="update table_name set colume ='i' where column_name is NOT NUll"

mysql -u username -p password mysql  <<EOF
$query;
EOF
```

The above script is not working

Comment: What error message do you get when executing the script?

Comment: `Query="..."`
...
`$query;`
Your problem is here...

Answer (score 6):

Mysql documentation is pretty clean:

```
#!bin/bash
query="update table_name set colume ='i' where column_name is NOT NUll"
mysql -u username -ppassword mysql -e "$query";
```

`-e` option allows to send an arbitrary query to the mysql server.

Notice that there is no space between `-p` and `password` - that is an intentional syntax of `mysql` CLI

Answer (score 5):

The above script is not working because the shell syntax is case-sensitive, and you used `Query` to define the variable, then `query` to expand it.

Otherwise, see @Kondybas 's answer for the proper way to do this.